# find unique a row of a data frame R

Tags: r, dataframe, row, unique

I have many columns (120) in a dataframe.
I would like to create a new column in this dataframe, with each row containing the unique values (ignoring NAs) from the values across each row in the 120 columns. For example:

```
V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
a a NA c d
c d e f e
x x x NA NA
```

a V6 column should be added

```
V6
a c d
c d e f
x
```

Any suggestion is more than welcome!

Wannes

Answer (score 1):

By using `apply` and `toString`

```
db$New=apply(db,1,function(x) toString(sort(unique(x[!is.na(x)]))))
db
  V1 V2   V3   V4   V5        New
1  a  a <NA>    c    d    a, c, d
2  c  d    e    f    e c, d, e, f
3  x  x    x <NA> <NA>          x
```

Or using `paste`

```
db$New=apply(db,1,function(x) paste(sort(unique(x[!is.na(x)]),collapse = ' ')))
db
  V1 V2   V3   V4   V5     New
1  a  a <NA>    c    d   a c d
2  c  d    e    f    e c d e f
3  x  x    x <NA> <NA>       x
```

The added `sort` ensures that the same set of unique values always appears in the same order.

Comment: It might also be worth wrapping the `unique()` in a `sort()`, so that the same unique sets always come out in the same order.

Comment: @AndrewGustar Yes you are right , please feel free to modify it ~ ;-)